# Timer + gregorianCalendar.getTime() not refreshing date properly

Tags: java, date, timer

where I made mistake? I tried to show current time in window every sec.
But it show

```
 ActionListener AL = new ActionListener() 
     {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
            Date currentTime=gregorianCalendarCurrrentTime.getTime();
            JLabelCurrentTime.setText(String.valueOf(currentTime));
        }
     };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, AL);
    timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that `gregorianCalendarCurrrentTime` is of type `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, the method `getTime()` returns a `Date` object which is representing the time of the calendar-objekt which was 'current' at creation time or after last use of set-methods of the calendar-objekt. The method does not determine the current time. To set the current time as labeltext, you simply could use `new Date()`.

```
LabelCurrentTime.setText(String.valueOf(new Date()));
```

Comment: That won't use so much memory on creating new objects of Date?

Comment: No, the scope of the Date-object is the call of valueOf. Because there is no reference  to the object after that call, the object is marked for garbage collection immediately.

Comment: And how can I show just h:min? I have to use Calendar somehow?

Comment: I managed to solve this: JLabelCurrentTime.setText(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())));     THX for help